# Не сохраняются файлы cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookie

Я делаю небольшой проект (сайт), и реализую простую проверку cookie файлов вместе с их созданием, но они почему-то удаляются при перезапуске браузера.

Вкратце, когда пользователь заходит на сайт, проверяется наличие id в его cookie файлах, и если их нет, то делается post запрос к моему api, который создает нового пользователя и возвращает его id обратно. И конкретно это работает как должно, но когда я закрываю браузер и снова захожу на сайт ( localhost ), то снова создается новый пользователь, а при обычной перезагрузке страницы все работает правильно и данные об id есть в cookie файлах.

Вот код моей проверки:

```
router.get('/pocketsage', jsonParser, (req, res) => {

    const DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL
    if (req.cookies._userID) {
        let userId = req.cookies._userID
        axios
            .get(`${DATABASE_URL}/db/${userId}`)
            .then(result => {
                let name = result.data[0].name
                let school = result.data[0].scnmb
                console.log(result.data)

                res.render('./pocketsage/main.ejs', {
                    name:name,
                    school:school,
                    userId: userId
                })
            })
    } else {
        axios
            .post(`http://${DATABASE_URL}/dbnew/newuser`)
            .then(result => {
                let id_ = result.data.id
                console.log(id_)
                console.log(req.cookies)
                console.log('No cookies')
                res.cookie('_userID', `${id_}`)
                res.redirect('localhost/pocketsage')
            })

    }
})
```

В настройках браузера все проверил, и даже скачал еще один, где разрешил все cookie, не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Стоит прочитать что-нибудь про [куки](https://doka.guide/js/cookie/) вообще и про [res.cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) в частности. Вы не указали срок жизни куки, поэтому она «сессионная», т.е. как раз и уничтожается при окончании сессии (закрытии браузера).

Comment: Спасибо, помогли, теперь все работает!